# Store the values of cells in an html table which is inside another html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, datatables

I have an HTML table which contains another HTML table in one of it's columns. The rows of the main table are selectable. My application loops through each selected row of the table. The tables use the DataTables plugin.

I want to be able to loop through the sub table of whatever row I have selected in the main table and store its values in a variable in JQuery. As per the snippet below, I want to be able to store the value of "pmc" in JQuery.

...

```html
 ...
 <td class="poolcss">
  <table id="poolstable "class="table table-condensed">
    @{
      foreach (var pool in node.pools)
      {
        @Html.Hidden("pmc", pool.TotalMemberCount)
        <tr class="poolRow">
        <td class="subPName">@pool.Name</td>
        <td id="poolmemberCount">@pool.TotalMemberCount</td>
        </tr>
      }
      }
 </table>
</td>
...
```

...

My Jquery function for the selected rows of the main table would be :

```html
table.on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
       // Get value of "pmc"
    });
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming `table` is a JQuery object representing the main table?

Comment: Jacob: Yes that is correct